# Внедрение зависимости MVVM

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

Изучаю WPF и MVVM и немного разобрался с принципами SOLID. В результате услышал о таких понятиях как DI и IoC. В сети много статей по этому поводу, но в основном все они слабо структуированы, из-за этого нет общей картины на что обращать внимание. В результате появился вопрос: с чего начать, в каком порядке и что нужно изучать, чтобы познать хорошую и гибкую архитектуру?

**UPD.** Есть уже готовые контейнеры DI, такие как Unity или Ninject. Хотелось бы услышать что это , насколько они нужны, и стоит ли вообще на них обращать внимание ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если Вы прочитали про SOLID, то должны были примерно понять, что такое DIP(Dependency inversion principle) - принцип инверсии зависимостей. Это когда у Вас код завязан на абстракциях и не деталях.

У DIP есть два правила:
- модули верхних уровней не должны зависеть от модулей нижних уровней. Оба типа модулей должны зависеть от абстракций.
- абстракции не должны зависеть от деталей. Детали должны зависеть от абстракций.

Если вы откроете и прочитаете принципы IoC, вы увидите тот же самый DIP. Это теория, а реализация теории называется IoC-контейнер. Это делается через:

- Шаблон "Фабрика" или Service locator
- Внедрение зависимости (англ. Dependency injection)

  - Через конструктор (англ. Constructor injection)
  - Через метод класса (англ. Setter injection)
  - Через интерфейс внедрения (англ. Interface injection)

Внедрение зависимостей достаточно просто и описание занимает около трех страниц печатного текста: https://habrahabr.ru/post/131993/

Все, что Вам остается, это следить за двумя правилами DIP и понимать, зависит ли Ваш класс от деталей или от абстракций(интерфейсов). Если Вы видите в коде, что обращаетесь к чему-то конкретному, а не к абстрактному, это надо исправить.

Comment: Этих принципов я стараюсь придерживаться. Я знаю, есть уже готовые контейнеры DI, такие как Unity или Ninject. Хотелось бы услышать что это , насколько они нужны, и стоит ли вообще на них обращать внимание ?

Comment: @Lightness, они упрощают внедрение зависимостей и дают возможность хранить привязки интерфейс->класс в одном месте. Unity я не смотрел, а вот у Ninject есть [хорошая страница вики](http://www.ninject.org/wiki.html), в которой показана как делается внедрение без Ninject(Dependency Injection By Hand) и вместе с Ninject(Dependency Injection With Ninject). Можно найти слева в меню Ninject->Introduction